# A list comprehension with two "fors" and a "if" condition

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have 2 lists:

```
>>> phrases = ['emp_sal','emp_addr']
>>> cols = ['emp_sal_total','emp_sal_monthly','emp_addr_primary','emp_ssn','emp_phone']
```

I am trying to use list comprehension and filter out **cols** such that only those values in **cols** should be picked that have a phrase **emp_sal** or **emp_addr** in them.

So, output should be:

```
['emp_sal_total','emp_sal_monthly','emp_addr_primary']
```

This is just a dummy example replicating the scenario. Actual example has a **cols** list of 180 odd columns.

Tried below solution:

```
new_cols = [c for c in cols if p for p in phrases in c]
```

It fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

Below approach yields a blank list:

```
  >>> [c for c in cols if p in c for p in phrases]
   []
```

Comment: I think you want `[c for c in cols for p in phrases if p in c]`

Comment: That works just well. was kinda close..:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to test if any string in phrases is in the current column your iterating over in `cols`. For this, use `any()`:

```
[c for c in cols if any(c.startswith(p) for p in phrases)]
```

The problem with your method was that you were trying to use `p` before it was defined, which raises a `NameError`:

```
>>> [c for c in cols if p in c for p in phrases]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'p' is not defined
```

As noted in the comments by @Hamms, you can still use something similar to your method. You just need to have defined `p` before trying to use it:

```
>>> [c for c in cols for p in phrases if p in c]
['emp_sal_total', 'emp_sal_monthly', 'emp_addr_primary']
>>>
```